# Node.js how to show a new index file, when something is finished

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a project and I have a problem. 
I'm using formidable to upload a txt file with X- and Y-Coordinates to my Node.js server. This file will be read and the X- and Y-Values will be stored in two variables (X: `obj[key1]` Y: `obj[key2]`)

Now I want the webserver to render a new webpage, which shows a graph with the X- and Y- Values.

This is how my reader.js file looks like right now:

```
var http = require('http'),  
    fs = require('fs'),
    express = require('express'), 
    app     = express(),  
    util = require('util'),
    fs   = require('fs-extra'), 
    formidable = require('formidable'); 

    //apps 
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile); 
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
   /* Process the form uploads */
  if (req.url == '/upload' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.end();
    });

   form.on('error', function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });

  form.on('end', function(fields, files) { 

    console.log('Form end called - File will be moved'); 
    /* Temporary location of our uploaded file */
        var temp_path = this.openedFiles[0].path;
    /* The file name of the uploaded file */
        var file_name = 'data.txt';
    /* Location where we want to copy the uploaded file */
        var new_location = 'C:/project/upload/';

        fs.copy(temp_path, new_location + file_name, function(err) {  
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                function readLines(input, done) {
                        // .. Reading file ..   
                } 

                //Opening uploaded file ..  
                var input = fs.createReadStream('upload/data.txt'); 
                if (err) { 
                    console.error(err); 
                } else { 
                readLines(input, done);
                } 

                function done(arr) {  

                    var obj = {};
                    var key1 = arr[0][0];
                    var key2 = arr[0][1];
                    obj[key1] = [];
                    obj[key2] = [];

                    arr.shift();

                    arr.forEach(function (item) {
                        obj[key1].push(item[0]);
                        obj[key2].push(item[1]);
                    });

                    console.log('Dateneingang X: ' + obj[key1]);  //Show the X-Values in Console 
                    console.log('Dateneingang Y: ' + obj[key2]);  //Show the Y-Values in the Console 

                    //Now use the Y Coordinates and send them to line.html  
                    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
                        res.render('line.html', {coordinates: obj[key2]});   
                    }); 
                }
            }
        });  
  });  

    return; 
}


  /* Display the file upload form. */
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(
    '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
    '<input type="text" name="title"><br>'+
    '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>'+
    '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
    '</form>'
  );

}).listen(8080);
```

The html file for the graph looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Spektrum</title>
        <script src="Chart.js"></script>
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1, user-scalable = no">
        <style>
            canvas{     

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>              
    <div style="width: 1000px; margin:0 auto;"> 
        <canvas id="canvas" height="500px" width="1000px"></canvas>   
    </div>  
    <script>
        var lineChartData = {
            labels : [ 385, 386 <!-- X-Values ..  --> ],
            datasets : [
                {
                    fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.831373)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "gba(76, 255, 178, 0.831373)",
<-- Y-Values should be rendered here -->data : [ <%= coordinates %>
                            ]
                }
            ]

        }

    var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData);

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem: I don't know how I can generate the new html file and show it to the user.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
     res.render('line.html', {coordinates: obj[key2]});   
});
```

Was a try to render a new file, but this doesn't work .. I just get an empty page with the title: localhost:8080/upload

I hope you have an idea how to solve my problem! :-)

JS

Comment: What is the **problem**?

Comment: Oops, totally forgot that. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can embed variables in a HTML like that. Why don't you create a complete/full EJS file in `views` directory with a name like `coordinates.ejs` and then try to render it? You can try it [here](http://runnable.com/EJS) before putting actual variables.

I believe it will work as soon as you write the template file properly.

Comment: Hm, I don't think that's the problem .. the res(end) is called right after the uploading process .. could that be the reason, why no new page is rendered? Do you have any idea how to solve that?